# Why does this code compile without errors in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have deleted all the constructors, even then following code is working perfectly. How and why ?

```
class Ax
{    
    public:
    
    Ax() = delete;
    Ax(Ax const&)=delete;
    Ax(Ax&&)=delete;
    void operator=(Ax const&)=delete;
    void operator=(Ax&&)=delete;

    void print()
    {
        cout << "Hello \n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{           
    Ax{}.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't if you replace `Ax{}.print();` with `Ax().print();`.

Comment: Doesn't compile with gcc10 / C++20 but still with gcc10 / C++17

Comment: @john thats true, But it should not work with uniform initialization syntax too i.e. {}. After all its just the constructor call.

Comment: @MartinMorterol I am using gcc 10.2 + c++17

Comment: @MartinMorterol [confirmed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c88ff4c75b5d1c5) otherwise.

Comment: @virus00x I'm using Visual Studo 2019.

Comment: c++20 gives correct result. Is this some kind of error. My projects' limitation is c++17.

Comment: C++20 : don't work for me : https://wandbox.org/permlink/bJoqztB1frxlqDYU

Comment: If we add `int a{};`it stops compiling, maybe some weird initialization take place in your example

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*(For a thorough walk-through of this topic, see the blog article [The fickle aggregate](https://dfrib.github.io/the-fickle-aggregate/))*

---

#### Aggregate initialization

Class `Ax` is an aggregate in C++11, C++14 and C++17, as it has no *user-provided* constructors, which means that `Ax{}` is *aggregate initialization*, bypassing any *user-declared* constructors, even deleted ones.

```
struct NonConstructible {
    NonConstructible() = delete;
    NonConstructible(const NonConstructible&) = delete;
    NonConstructible(NonConstructible&&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    //NonConstructible nc;  // error: call to deleted constructor

    // Aggregate initialization (and thus accepted) in
    // C++11, C++14 and C++17.
    // Rejected in C++20 (error: call to deleted constructor).
    NonConstructible nc{};
}
```

The definition of what is an aggregate class has changed through various standard versions (C++11 through C++20), and these rules can have somewhat surprising consequences. As of C++20, particularly due to the implementation of

- [P1008R1: Prohibit aggregates with user-declared constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf)

most of the frequently surprising aggregate behaviour has been addressed, specifically by no longer allowing aggregates to have *user-declared* constructors, a stricter requirement for a class to be an aggregate than just prohibiting *user-provided* constructors.

---

#### User-provided or only user-declared explicitly-defaulted constructors

Note that providing an *explicitly-defaulted* (or deleted) definition out-of-line counts as a *user-provided* constructor, meaning that in the following example, `B` has a user-provided default constructor, whereas `A` does not:

```
struct A {
    A() = default; // not user-provided.
    int a;
};

struct B {
    B(); // user-provided.
    int b;
};

// Out of line definition: a user-provided
// explicitly-defaulted constructor.
B::B() = default;
```

with the result that `A` is an aggregate, whereas `B` is not. This, in turn, means that initialization of `B` by means of an empty *direct-list-init* will result in its data member `b` being left in an uninitialized state. For `A`, however, the same initialization syntax will result in (via aggregate initialization of the `A` object and subsequent value initalization of its data member a) zero-initialization of its data member `a`:

```
A a{};
// Empty brace direct-list-init:
// -> A has no user-provided constructor
// -> aggregate initialization
// -> data member 'a' is value-initialized
// -> data member 'a' is zero-initialized

B b{};
// Empty brace direct-list-init:
// -> B has a user-provided constructor
// -> value-initialization
// -> default-initialization
// -> the explicitly-defaulted constructor will
//    not initialize the data member 'b'
// -> data member 'b' is left in an unititialized state
```

This may come as a surprise, and with the obvious risk of reading the uninitialized data member `b` with the result of undefined behaviour:

```
A a{};
B b{};     // may appear as a sound and complete initialization of 'b'.
a.a = b.b; // reading uninitialized 'b.b': undefined behaviour.
```

Comment: So `=delete` counts as user-provided?

Comment: @Quimby No. Explicitly-deleted and explicitly-defaulted definitions provided _at first declaration_ does not count as user-provided. Providing these explicitly-defaulted definitions _out-of-line_ counts as user-provided, but a separate rule is that `= delete` may not be used out of line (ill-formed), with the result that `= delete` will never count as user-provided. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fkyGvwhN0ztSaNdY).

Comment: @dfri Well, that is what I thought too. But from the paper, p.8, the proposed wording is "no user-provided, explicit,user-declared or inherited constructors ", so `=delete` must count as user-provided since the next section of the proposal lists such example as " Not an aggregate".

Comment: @dfri Reading more, the three examples at the bottom of p.8 also disallow `B()=default` as not agreggate in contradiction to your example, am I reading it wrongly?

Comment: @Quimby My whole previous comment applies to what is used-provided. You are mixing topics w.r.t. the paper (P1008R1): the paper focuses on changing _what is an aggregate_ but not _what counts as user-provided_. In C++20 you can't even _declare_ a constructor for an aggregate class. This is the essence of the (accepted) proposal, that any class with user-declared ctors (deleted, defaulted of just not defined) should never be an aggregate. Note that also in C++20, both `Foo() = default;` and `Foo() = delete;` counts as user-provided, but this no longer has relevance for aggregates.

Answer (score 12):

In C++17, your example is an aggregate. For C++17 aggregates only need to have no user-provided constructors; user-declared (but explicitly deleted or defaulted) constructors are fine.

In this case, then, aggregate initialization is performed when you do `Ax{}`, which doesn't call any of the constructors... including the deleted ones, and so this compiles.

In C++20 the rules were changed so that any user-declared constructors prevent the type from being an aggregate, and so the example will fail to compile.

See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization